# PostgreSQL: Show all the privileges for a concrete user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql, privileges

How to make a query to the Postgres data dictionary to find out all the privileges that a particular user has.

I've been looking for a solution and I can not find anything. Thanks and good day

Answer (score 127, accepted):

**Table permissions:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
 WHERE grantee = 'YOUR_USER';
```

**Ownership:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM pg_tables 
 WHERE tableowner = 'YOUR_USER';
```

**Schema permissions:**

```
      SELECT r.usename AS grantor,
             e.usename AS grantee,
             nspname,
             privilege_type,
             is_grantable
        FROM pg_namespace
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT *
                FROM aclexplode(nspacl) AS x) a
          ON true
        JOIN pg_user e
          ON a.grantee = e.usesysid
        JOIN pg_user r
          ON a.grantor = r.usesysid 
       WHERE e.usename = 'YOUR_USER';
```

Comment: Great solution(s) but for schema permission, you don't need a join lateral. Simply `... FROM pg_namespace, aclexplode(nspacl) AS a ...`

Comment: Not sure what this does, but all query results are empty. Yet my user can access their own databases, tables and even peek into foreign databases and create/delete new tables there! This answer doesn't help.

Comment: @ygoe: if a user owns a table (or database), no special grant exists as the owner of an object always has full access to that object (without grants)

Comment: Note: `JOIN LATERAL` is available in Postgres from version 9.3 thus the `schema permissions` query above will not work in AWS Redshift.

Comment: That seems all fine and good for database *objects*.  How does one find the existing privs for a role to the databases *themselves*? thanks

Comment: would you mind, to spell out the display of SCHEMA privileges in more detail @Jeff?

Comment: This Schema permissions query does not work well, particularly with AWS, because `pg_user` only has users that can log in, so the joins fail when grants are made by roles which cannot log in, which is the usual case for AWS, and because it ignores permissions granted via `PUBLIC`. I suggest you use [my query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77603661/712765) instead.

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked for me the best. short and clean.

`\du` lists all user accounts and roles and `\du+` is the extended version which shows even more information.

```sh
# \du
                                        List of roles
     Role name      |                         Attributes                         | Member of
--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 padmin             | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 test               |                                                            | {}
 postgres           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 root               | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

```sh
# \du+
                                               List of roles
     Role name      |                         Attributes                         | Member of | Description
--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------
 padmin             | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}        |
 test               |                                                            | {}        |
 postgres           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}        |
 root               | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}        |
```

Comment: This query shows attributes, the question asks for privileges.

Answer (score 8):

This command was helpful for me:

```
\l
```

**Here's how I used it**:

```
postgres=# \l

                        List of databases
 Name   | Owner    | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |          Access privileges          
------------------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------------------------
 mydb1  | postgres | UTF8     | en_NG   | en_NG | =Tc/postgres                       +
        |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres              +
        |          |          |         |       | myuser=CTc/postgres
 mydb2  | postgres | UTF8     | en_NG   | en_NG | =Tc/postgres                       +
        |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres              +
        |          |          |         |       | my_user=CTc/postgres
```

**Resources**: [PostgreSQL: List the database privileges using psql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/list-the-database-privileges-using-psql)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Vao Tsun regarding how to see permissions for schemas is outdated and potentially hides a lot of results (because `pg_user` only has users that can log in, so the joins fail when the grantor or grantee is a role that cannot log in). Use this instead:

### Show schema permissions (2023)

The following lists schemas and permissions for the current database.

```sql
WITH users AS (select rolname, oid
               from pg_roles
               union
               select 'PUBLIC', 0)
SELECT r.rolname AS grantor,
       e.rolname AS grantee,
       nspname   as schema,
       privilege_type,
       is_grantable
FROM pg_namespace,
     aclexplode(nspacl) AS a
     JOIN users AS e
          ON a.grantee = e.oid
     JOIN users AS r
          ON a.grantor = r.oid
-- Add a WHERE clause to limit results to a single user
-- WHERE e.rolname = 'PUBLIC' or e.rolname = 'THE_ROLE_YOU_WANT'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script to retrieve all priviliges for all PostgreSQL roles (server level, db ownership, object ownership, object permission, schema permissions). Add filters to get privileges for a specific user

```
WITH server_permissions AS (
        SELECT 
            r.rolname, 
            'Server_Permissions' AS "Level", 
            r.rolsuper, 
            r.rolinherit,
            r.rolcreaterole, 
            r.rolcreatedb, 
            r.rolcanlogin,
            ARRAY(
                SELECT b.rolname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
                JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON m.roleid = b.oid
                WHERE m.member = r.oid
            ) AS memberof,
            r.rolbypassrls
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
        WHERE r.rolname !~ '^pg_'
    ),
    
    db_ownership AS (
        SELECT 
            r.rolname, 
            'DB_Ownership' AS "Level", 
            d.datname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d, pg_catalog.pg_roles r
        WHERE d.datdba = r.oid
    ),
    
    schema_permissions AS (
        SELECT
            'Schema Permissions' AS "Level",                
            r.rolname AS role_name,
            nspname AS schema_name,
            pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'CREATE') AS create_grant,
            pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'USAGE') AS usage_grant
        FROM pg_namespace pn, pg_catalog.pg_roles r
        WHERE array_to_string(nspacl, ',') LIKE '%' || r.rolname || '%' 
              AND nspowner > 1
    ),
    
    table_ownership AS (
        SELECT 
            'Table Ownership' AS "Level",
            tableowner, 
            schemaname, 
            tablename
        FROM pg_tables
        GROUP BY tableowner, schemaname, tablename
    ),
    
    object_permissions AS (
        SELECT  
            'Object Permissions' AS "Level",
            COALESCE(NULLIF(s[1], ''), 'public') AS rolname,
            n.nspname,
            relname, 
            CASE 
                WHEN relkind = 'm' THEN 'Materialized View'
                WHEN relkind = 'p' THEN 'Partitioned Table'
                WHEN relkind = 'S' THEN 'Sequence'
                WHEN relkind = 'I' THEN 'Partitioned Index'
                WHEN relkind = 'v' THEN 'View'
                WHEN relkind = 'i' THEN 'Index'
                WHEN relkind = 'c' THEN 'Composite Type'
                WHEN relkind = 't' THEN 'TOAST table'
                WHEN relkind = 'r' THEN 'Table'
                WHEN relkind = 'f' THEN 'Foreign Table'
            END AS "Object Type",
            s[2] AS privileges
        FROM 
            pg_class c
            JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = relnamespace
            JOIN pg_roles r ON r.oid = relowner,
            UNNEST(COALESCE(relacl::text[], FORMAT('{%s=arwdDxt/%s}', rolname, rolname)::text[])) acl, 
            REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(acl, '=|/') s 
        WHERE relkind <> 'i' AND relkind <> 't'
    )   
    
    SELECT 
        "Level", 
        rolname AS "Role", 
        'N/A' AS "Object Name", 
        'N/A' AS "Schema Name", 
        'N/A' AS "DB Name", 
        'N/A' AS "Object Type", 
        'N/A' AS "Privileges", 
        rolsuper::text AS "Is SuperUser", 
        rolinherit::text,
        rolcreaterole::text, 
        rolcreatedb::text, 
        rolcanlogin::text,
        memberof::text,
        rolbypassrls::text 
    FROM server_permissions
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT 
        dow."Level", 
        dow.rolname,
        'N/A',  
        'N/A', 
        datname,
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A'
    FROM db_ownership AS dow 
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT
        "Level", 
        role_name, 
        'N/A', 
        schema_name, 
        'N/A', 
        'N/A',
        CASE 
            WHEN create_grant IS TRUE AND usage_grant IS TRUE THEN 'Usage+Create' 
            WHEN create_grant IS TRUE AND usage_grant IS FALSE THEN 'Create' 
            WHEN create_grant IS FALSE AND usage_grant IS TRUE THEN 'Usage' 
            ELSE 'None' 
        END, 
        'N/A', 
        'N/A', 
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A'
    FROM schema_permissions
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT 
        "Level", 
        tableowner, 
        tablename, 
        schemaname,
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A'
    FROM table_ownership
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT 
        "Level", 
        rolname, 
        relname,  
        nspname, 
        'N/A', 
        "Object Type", 
        privileges,
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A'
    FROM object_permissions
    ORDER BY "Role";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use this to see if your user has anything other than SELECT

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.role_table_grants WHERE grantee = 'username' AND with_hierarchy = 'YES'`