# how to check to which databases a postgres role has access to

Tags: postgresql, psql

i am trying to create a role which has read only access to all existing databases we have, i have given the role read access to one database

is there a command using which I can what databases a role has been given access to?

with the command `\du+` I see

```
Role name, Attributes, Member Of, Description
```

But where can a I find a list of databases a role has been given access to.

Thanks

Comment: `\l+` lists databases and iirc also the permissions of all users with access, not just the owner

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/list-the-database-privileges-using-psql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check all roles/user/group\_role have what privileges in postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858343/how-to-check-all-roles-user-group-role-have-what-privileges-in-postgres-database) or [Show all the privileges for a concrete user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40759177/1048572)