# Npgsql getting "procedure does not exist"

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Here is the relevant C# code:

```
NpgsqlConnection? con = null;

try
{
        RawFileInfo rfi = CreateRawFileInfo(blobData);

        if (rfi == null || rfi.Ids.Count == 0) 
            return;

        con = new NpgsqlConnection(postgresConnection);
        con.Open();

        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL shipment_status.updatefilelocation()".ToLower(), con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, rfi.Ids.ToArray());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text, rfi.RawDataStorageLinks.ToArray());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(NpgsqlDbType.Integer, rfi.Ids.Count - 1);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And here is the relevant procedure, created using PGAdmin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE shipment_status.updatefilelocation(
    ids_to_update uuid[],
    files_to_update text[],
    start_with integer,
    end_with integer)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE counter INT;
BEGIN
    counter := start_with;
    WHILE counter <= end_with LOOP
        UPDATE shipment_status."RawShipmentStatusMissingSCACCode"
        SET "RawDataStorageLink" = files_to_update[counter]
        WHERE "Id" = ids_to_update[counter];
        
        UPDATE shipment_status."RawShipmentStatusMissingStatusCodeMap"
        SET "RawDataStorageLink" = files_to_update[counter]
        WHERE "Id" = ids_to_update[counter];
        
        counter := counter + 1;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
$BODY$;
```

However, when I execute the C#, I get the exception:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: 42883: procedure shipment_status.updatefilelocation() does not exist
>
> POSITION: 6

I have scoured the documentation (and this site), trying to see where I am going wrong... I have tried numerous variations of the procedure call, but have not figured out what is the issue; perhaps the signature of the procedure call itself from C#?

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: 1) Ascertain the store proc exists.  2)Ascertain the db user you are using in conn string has  privilege to call the stored proc [Show all the privileges for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759633/7450780)

Comment: the place holders are missing: `updatefilelocation()`. This function doesn't exist since you created one with 4 input parameters. So you need 4 place holders in your code

Comment: should you not be calling `prepare` method as well before calling `AddWithValue` methods ? Have you tried creating a named parameter and then setting its value. I somewhere saw in SO that AddWithValue() has some issues. Refer the official [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#positional-and-named-placeholders) for filling parameter values.

Comment: explicit invoking of `prepare` is suggested by Npgsql, see [here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html#introduction)

Comment: Frank Heikens I am unsure what those placeholders would look like in the call?

I have tried that, but am pretty sure I got it wrong...

Comment: Anand Sowmithirian thank you, I will try this also, and review the documentation (again) :)

I started with named parameters, and went to AddWithValue, but I can surely try the other way as well.

Comment: Denis Michael 
I am connecting using the same authentication that created the proc itself; that user has full privileges, thanks.

Comment: Anand Sowmithiran interestingly, when I add a "cmd.Prepare" after adding the parameters (but before setting their values, as the documentation demonstrates), I get the stored proc does not exist error on the "cmd.Prepare" statement now. Hmm.

Comment: SOLVED: 
added placeholders using "@parameter_name" to the CALL signature.

The proc seems to have executed. However, my updates did not occur, although no exceptions were thrown. That's the next thing to figure out.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Side note: you need to dispose the connection and command with `using`.